# MySQL/PHP Error:[2002] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I couldn't find a solution to this already on stackoverflow, most other related topics had to do with Apache not starting first and getting this error. My issue is that after apache is running some of my users that are connected to our php/mysql website will receive this error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]:
[2002] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
is normally permitted.
```

This seems to be totally random and when I monitor my worker threads for Apache, there are typically lots of idle workers available to accept new connections/requests.

My Site is running on Windows XP SP3, Xampp 1.7.7, Quad Core, 4gigs of RAM, 1TB HD, Specs for php/mysql:

Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Any help on what I should change in any of my configurations to make this go away would be greatly appreciated. I've looked on google and even on Xampp forums but most people experience this issue prior to launching Apache, but Apache is running fine for me when users are experiencing this error.

Comment: are you using persistent connections? What kind of user usage do you have (concurrent)

Comment: I am not using mysql_pconnect, at the moment we have around 200 concurrent users and I have my httpd-mpm set for win_nt to give us about 350 threads, at the moment if I look at server-status apache has about 237 requests at the moment and about 100 idle give or take but a the moment it is fluctuating around this.

Comment: I did notice yesterday that we had a huge spike in requests to apache, increased from 150 to 272 insantly and apache crashed, unfortunately I had access.log off during the time. I re-enabled it in case it happens again today so i can catch what ip they were coming from if it happens again. We are on a secure intranet network and nobody can access it from outside easily.

Comment: Apache server-status shows as currently:

239 requests currently being processed, 111 idle workers
K_KKK__KCKKKKKK___KK_KK_KKKKKKKKCKKKKKK__KK_K_KK_K___K_KKCKKKKKK
K__K_KKKKKKK_KK_K___KKK_K_KKCKKKKK_KK_K_K_KKKK_K_KKK_K____KKKKK_
KKK_KKK_KKKKKKWK_CK_K_KKK_KK__KKKKKKKKKKKK_C__K___KKK_K_K_KK_K_K
K___KKCWKK__K_KKKKKK_KK__K__KK_CK_KKK_KKKW__KKKCKKKKCKKKK_KKKKKK
KK_K_K__KK_K__K__KK__K_KK_K_K_K_K__KK_KK_KKK_KKKK___CK_KKK_KKKKC
CKKKKKKKK_KK_KC_KKK____K_K_K_K..................................
....................................

Comment: I'm curious if it could be an issue with a setting I changed with keepalivetimeout yesterday, I lowered it to 2, I've since put it back to 15 and restarted apache, so far no issues but not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 23):

you can modify windows `REGISTRY` to fix that,

first in regedit open this path:

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters

and create 4 new `DWORD` as this key and values:

```
TcpTimedWaitDelay
REG_DWORD: 0000001e (hex)

MaxUserPort
REG_DWORD: 0000fffe (hex)

TcpNumConnections
REG_DWORD: 00fffffe (hex)

TcpMaxDataRetransmissions
REG_DWORD: 00000005 (hex)
```

like with this screen shot:

[image]

[reference](https://deploymentresearch.com/research/post/532/fix-for-windows-10-exhausted-pool-of-tcp-ip-ports)

Comment: Thanks.  By the way, the article you referenced seems to claim this is a Window 10 issue.  Windows 10 was released 2015 and the question was posted in 2012...  However, I'm having this problem in 2018 and your answer solved it for me, so kudos!

Comment: @hemnathmouli I hope to help you

Answer (score 12):

The error isn't actually coming from MySQL, but [from Windows itself](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/470766.aspx):

> When a connection is closed, on the side that is closing the connection the 5 tuple 
>   { Protocol, Local IP, Local Port, Remote IP, Remote Port} goes into a TIME_WAIT state for 240 seconds by default.
>
> In this case, the protocol is fixed - TCP
>
> The local IP, remote IP and remote PORT are also typically fixed. So the variable is the local port.
>
> What happens is that when you don't bind a port in the range 1024-5000 is used. 
>   So roughly you have 4000 ports. If you use all of them in 4 minutes - meaning roughly you 
>   make 16 web service calls per second for 4 minutes you will exhaust all the ports. That is the cause of this exception.

In other words, you've run out of ports in the dynamic range.  That probably shouldn't be happening.  How many concurrent users are you dealing with here?

The linked blog has workarounds:

1. Increase the dynamic port range through registry editing.
2. Reduce the time the system wants connections to spent in `TIME_WAIT` through registry editing.
3. Run a bit of code to do the above registry edit without regedit.

What a wide variety of workarounds!

See also [this question on the Visual Studio forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/a595c417-10dc-4b06-b4c2-490c8abe776d), which explains:

> The port will be locked for another minute or two to catch all packets which might have been sent before the application was terminated but haven't arrived yet.  In Winsock API you can set socket option SO_REUSEADDR to resolve this (also this option can be set in .NET Socket class), but TcpListener is too high-level and doesn't let you set this option.

It's very likely that the underlying code to connect to MySQL or the code that handles connections in Apache isn't trying to use `SO_REUSEADDR`.

I'm going bet that your changing of the keepalive timeout had a direct impact here.  Even though reducing it *theoretically* frees up the socket, Windows disagrees and keeps the socket reserved.

Comment: The [dynamic port range changed starting with Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929851): Start port: 49152
End port: 65535. You can see the current settings using the `netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp` command.

Answer (score 8):

This is the [Doldurma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1830228/doldurma) answer but for lazy people, you just have to place this inside a .reg file and than click it (reboot was not required in my case)

File content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]

"TcpTimedWaitDelay"=dword:0000001e
"MaxUserPort"=dword:0000fffe
"TcpNumConnections"=dword:00fffffe
"TcpMaxDataRetransmissions"=dword:00000005
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks from the bottom of my lazy heart.

Comment: same here :-)  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Happens to me when developing my Laravel projects. For developmental purposes, it's no biggie especially when you are using windows system. But for production, I simply run on Linux and problem solved.
Also, change the MySQL connection from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" if possible.

Comment: Do note that this question has been asked over six years ago, has several answers providing information, and your answer gives no new insight or resolution for the problem. Please refrain from digging up old questions unless you have an actual unposted solution for them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple Work around on this.

Download CurrPorts http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html  - a standalone freeware tool that lists was programs and services are using which ports.  Sure, you can use netstat, the Windows Administrative Tools, and  Task Manager to figure this out yourself, but CurrPorts does that all for you.

Run Currports as administrator >> Select the service/application that creating problem by running to same port >> Stop the service. To stop service -

1. Direct from Currports application.
2. Start>>Run>>service.msc>> (select from the list).
3. TaskManager.

Hope you boost me up by polling.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to the party, but I recently had this issue but wasn't able to fix it via the the regedit. Turns out I was calling PDO twice (I'm using PDO instead but connecting to MYSQL). My solution was to only use the initial $connection that I made

```
$connection = new PDO(connectionString);
```

and passing it from the top of the script to any helper functions or classes I used.

Answer (score -1):

FWIW, I had the same issue on a similar setup (Windows XP). The same code worked without this issue on Mac (OS X).

I resolved the issue by using a persistent connection within the MySQLi class.

See here for more information: http://php.net/mysqli.persistconns

Make sure you are aware of all the gotchas / caveats associated to using a persistent connection.

Comment: This is not fixing the issue but going around it. Persistent connections behave so much differently that they require you to be very careful of how you code your app. Unless you're familiar with them or you only turning them on on your local machine, I would not recommend it. This solution might create a lot more issues than it would fix.