# SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Each socket address (protocol/network address/port) can normally be used only once

Tags: php, mysql, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL/PHP Error:[2002] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317974/mysql-php-error2002-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-a)

I'm getting the following error at total random:

SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Each socket address (protocol/network address/port) can normally be used only once.

Also, mysql reports the following errors:

Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. The statement is unsafe because it uses a LIMIT clause. This is unsafe because the set of rows included cannot be predicted. Statement: UPDATE `sessions` SET `page`='x.php' WHERE `sessname`='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' LIMIT 1

(I don't get this error, since the table has a PRIMARY_INDEX on SessionID (auto_increment) and UNIQUE on sessname)

Is the problem above (SQL STATE) related to the problem below or is there another issue ?

The error above (SQL STATE) also occures on excessive F5 (refreshing)

Please help!

(EDIT: I'm using apache 2.2.22, php5.4.3, mysql5.5.24)
(EDIT: /system32/drivers/etc/hosts 127.0.0.1 localhost, is the only entry)

Comment: i already viewed that topic, but it's not of any help to me

Comment: It will be, as ten seconds in Google has revealed the answer that I'll be posting there shortly.  :p

Comment: Remove the limit clause (sessname is unique)

Comment: isn't removing the limit clause a security issue ?

Comment: I'd remove the limit personnally, but if you're keep on keeping it, adding an order by clause might get rid of the error since the 1 row is no longer "random"

Comment: thanks, that might be a good idea, but still, i can't believe that the SQLSTATE error comes from the Unsafe Statement error, or am I wrong ?

Comment: If there's only row where `sessname='xxxx'`, because the column is unique, then it will only update that one row. The limit clause is redundant. Or you can just ignore the error, since you know it's not a problem.

Comment: I don't think the SQLSTATE error has anything to do with the log warning.

Comment: See the answer Charles just added in the linked question.

Comment: do you know what might cause the SQL STATE error ?

Comment: i'm going to try both ideas, first the ORDER BY, and if it doesn't works, i'll remove the limit, thanks tho!

Comment: btw, i'm using PHP PDO to connect (multiple PDO's)

Comment: It's only a development machine, but i'm using Windows XP Professional SP3 with Wampserver (64-bit)

Comment: So, Charles' answer is probably right. You have a large number of connection/disconnection and the used sockets grow faster than the timeout period. Look at his answer on the other post, or see if you can reuse connections somwhow.

Comment: is this an apache configuration error ?

Comment: i haven't seen Charles his post yet ?

Comment: No, it's a Windows "feature". Check the link in the first comment