# Laravel 5.4 Database - Max connection and Socket Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, azure

I use laravel for chat app on Azure with ClearDB (venus 15 connection DB). Sometimes I got max connection error, sometimes I got this socket error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

Any solution to fix the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: As @paperclip said in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317974/mysql-php-error2002-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-a/17810539#17810539), you can resolve the issue by using a [persistent connection](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php) within the MySQLi class.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes I got max connection error

Perhaps your application either sends too many requests or the database reaches its resource limits. There is a maximum number of connections each pricing tier for ClearDB MySQL databases.

When too many connections are reached, you may receive the following error:

```
ERROR 1040 (08004): Too many connections
```

You generally have two options to fix this.

1. Reduce the number of incoming requests to the database.
2. Upgrade your ClearDB database from one plan to another to fit your needs.

> sometimes I got this socket error

This error indicates that you are exhausting all the available network ports on the ClearDB server machine. A much more in-depth article describing the issue:

https://support.socketlabs.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/61/0/how-to-fix-error-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocolnetwork-addressport-is-normally-permitted