# The "Only one usage of each socket address" error in ZF3 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, windows-server-2008, zend-db

I'm migrating the DBAL of a Zend Framework 3 application to Doctrine. The migration of the data retrieving part is completed. The data saving is yet remaining to be `Zend\Db` driven.

Now I want to deploy the new version to the server and get this error:

> [PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Only one usage of each socket
>   address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. in
>   D:\Path\to\my-project\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php:266

The error doesn't occur on my local Debian virtual machine, but only when running PHPUnit on the Windows Server.

Just took a look into the [Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php:266](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/d2c0e4f00fd46639cd1d6f3c4c55ec32646496ae/src/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Connection.php#L266). It's the place, where `Zend\Db` tries to create a new connection.

Since this problem hasn't been observed before, I suppose, that it's related to the (partial) migration to Doctrine. Maybe the application doesn't close a database connection opened for `Zend\Db` and tries to open a new one with exactly the same settings for Doctrine. Or vice versa: A PDO connection for Doctrine is opened and in the same time the framework tries to open a new one for `Zend\Db`.

How to resolve this issue and work with both Doctrine and `Zend\Db`?

Answer (score 0):

I have been running into this with PDO as well. My research into it suggests that this has nothing to do with MySQL or PHP, but has to do with Windows. You are making too many requests too quickly. When windows closes a port it puts it in time_wait state for up to 240 seconds (default) and that port cannot be used until it comes out of the time_wait state.

[related to this stack overflow question from 2012:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317974/mysql-php-error2002-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-a)