# Error MySQL connection access denied

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2002

I can't connect to MySQL database. I try to connect to MySQL but meet this error. I change port & host but nothing happens.

Access Denied:

[image: Access Denied]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL/PHP Error:\[2002\] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317974/mysql-php-error2002-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-a)