# One usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, windows-10, wamp

I'm getting this error sometimes when I try to connect to a mysql database using PHP:

> "one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

This is the connection string that I'm using:

> $con4=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","usuario","senha","bd");

I'm using a Windows 10 with Wamp with PHP 5.6.40 and MySQL 5.7.24

I have already changed these regedit parameters to these values:

> TcpTimedWaitDelay
>      REG_DWORD: 0000001e (hex)
>
> MaxUserPort
>      REG_DWORD: 0000fffe (hex)
>
> TcpNumConnections
>      REG_DWORD: 00fffffe (hex)
>
> TcpMaxDataRetransmissions
>      REG_DWORD: 00000005 (hex)

One note is that it takes a couple of days to see the errors after I reboot the server.

Any advice is really appreciated!

Comment: check if anything is running on 3306 port

Comment: The problem is not happening when I try to start the Mysql server but when I try to connect to it after it is running for a couple of days.
And the error doesn't happen every time
So, MySQL is running on 3306 port

Comment: This answer explains the problem, at least as I see it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024933/2620838

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL/PHP Error:\[2002\] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317974/mysql-php-error2002-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-a)

Comment: @KateOrlova I don't think that it is a duplicate as I did what is suggested there and it didn't solved the problem

Comment: I said in the question which parameteres I have changed and to which values
The issue may be because the Windows version is different but I googled and haven't found a solution