# (closed) mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I was trying to run some queries with PHP and MySql but I got this error: `Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted`. And when I tried to enter PHPMyAdmin I got this error: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. I am on a computer running Windows 11 and using ReactJS for the front end.

I think it might be because my JavaScript is causing the same queries to be run all the time, but I'm not sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317974/mysql-php-error2002-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-a might help

Comment: I am not being able to write to the registry, and the other answers didn't help.

Comment: Unless you find you have another process already running on the port mysql is trying to use, then if you can't modify the registry it's not clear what solution you could use

Comment: I couldn't add a value because I got this error: Cannot create value: Error writing to the registry.

Comment: Did you run the registry editor as admin?

Comment: See also https://www.howtogeek.com/262464/how-to-gain-full-permissions-to-edit-protected-registry-keys/

Comment: By running the Regedit in administrator mode I was able to add the values. Thanks!

Comment: Should I close the question?

Comment: I've voted to close it as a duplicate of the one I linked to initially. So eventually it will likely be closed because of others making the same vote. Nothing you need to do, unless you prefer to just delete it.

Comment: Ok. I want to keep it open in case the same error occurs later

Comment: Being closed as a duplicate just means it won't accept answers (because people can go and put their answers on the original one), but it won't be deleted, or at least not for a while.